# Leaflet Draw Plugin: How to hide/show drawing tools by Layer Type dynamically

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using draw plugin in my project and I would like to know how can I hide/show drawing tools by layer type?

For example, let's say I have 2 layers one of them type is Polygon and the other one is Line.

If user select **Polygon layer**, I want to **hide Line drawing tool**.

After that, If user select **Line layer**, I want to **hide Polygon drawing tool**. I've looked [here](http://leafletjs.com/2013/02/20/guest-post-draw.html) but this example is making tools static, I want to change *dynamically*. How can I do that?

Every suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I solved it myself. I'm adding this draw control when map initialized.

```
 drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw : {
        position : 'topleft',
        polygon : false,
        polyline : false,
        rectangle : false,
        circle : false

    },
    edit : false
});

map.addControl(drawControl);
```

After that, i wrote a function for resetting drawing tools.

```
  function setDrawingTools(layerType) {

    map.removeControl(drawControl);

    if (layerType == 'Polygon') {

        drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            draw : {
                position : 'topleft',
                polygon : {
                    title : 'Draw a sexy polygon!',
                    allowIntersection : false,
                    drawError : {
                        color : '#b00b00',
                        timeout : 1000
                    },
                    shapeOptions : {
                        color : '#bada55'
                    },
                    showArea : true
                },
                polyline : false,
                rectangle : false,
                circle : false,
                marker : false
            },
            edit : false
        });
    } else if (layerType == 'Line') {

        drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            draw : {
                position : 'topleft',
                polygon : false,
                polyline : {
                    metric : false
                },
                rectangle : false,
                circle : false,
                marker : false
            },
            edit : false
        });
    } else if (layerType == 'Point') {

        drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
            draw : {
                position : 'topleft',
                polygon : false,
                polyline : false,
                rectangle : false,
                circle : false

            },
            edit : false
        });

    }
    map.addControl(drawControl);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, myself, but couldn't you alternatively create both controls up front and then simply add/remove them per the condition? It might be slightly less resource intensive than recreating the control from scratch every time.

Comment: @Emre HI, i am new in leaflet. i am interested to know how you are working leaflet with draw plug-in. would u create a demo in jsfiddle so i may see and get some idea. thanks

Comment: The 'position' option should be in root object, not in 'draw', at least for Leaflet.draw 0.2.4.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful.

Comment: How do I hide the circle Marker toolbar item??

Answer (score 6):

It appears you can't do that with the plugin, but you can use CSS to show/hide certain drawing tools when you switch layers.

The buttons have classes like `leaflet-draw-draw-polyline`, `leaflet-draw-draw-polygon`, etc.

Comment: This solution deserves more votes!  1 and done: $('.leaflet-draw-draw-polygon').hide();

Comment: @biomiker it appears that the classes changed and one can only get the controls by their respective icons. Hence hide the parent now with `$('.leaflet-pm-icon-circle').parent().hide()`. Like this, the control bar is automatically resized and no artifacts left.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to gain better control of you layers. Difficult to say without any code posted. Have you considered adding and removing your layers upon user selection? [Here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html) is some documentation on manipulating layers. And the syntax would be something like:

```
map.addLayer(layer_in_question);
```

or

```
map.removeLayer(layer_in_question);
```

Comment: I wasn't trying to add or remove layer into the map. I was trying to customize drawing tool by layer Type.

Answer (score 0):

I use a input named geometria where I get the geometry of layer

```
map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
  let geotipo =  $('#geometria').val();
 
  if (geotipo ==="MultiPolygon"){
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-polygon').show();
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-polyline').hide();
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-marker').hide();
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-circlemarker').show();
  }else if(geotipo === "MultiLineString"){
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-polygon').hide();
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-polyline').show();
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-marker').hide();
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-circlemarker').hide();
  }else if (geotipo === "Point"){
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-polygon').hide();
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-polyline').hide();
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-marker').show();
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-circlemarker').hide();
  }else{
    $('.leaflet-draw-draw-polygon').hide();
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-polyline').hide();
  $('.leaflet-draw-draw-marker').hide();
  alert('Tipo de mapa no identificado');
  }
  }
```