# How can I change my leaflet.draw units from imperial to metric?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I've been building a leaflet map that allows users to draw a custom selection with the circle tool. The source code tells me that I can change the tool tip notice into metrics, but I have no clue how to achieve this.

> Radius: 1239 ft

I'd like to change it to:

> Radius: 377 m

Visual reference:
[image: Visual reference]

**Leaflet.draw function that is being called to display the radius:**

```
// Leaflet.draw.js
readableDistance: function(t, e, i, o) {
    var n, s;
    switch (s = "string" == typeof e ? e : i ? "feet" : o ? "nauticalMile" : e ? "metric" : "yards") {
        case "metric":
            n = t > 1e3 ? (t / 1e3).toFixed(2) + " km" : Math.ceil(t) + " m";
            break;
        case "feet":
            t *= 3.28083, n = Math.ceil(t) + " ft";
            break;
        case "nauticalMile":
            t *= .53996, n = (t / 1e3).toFixed(2) + " nm";
            break;
        case "yards":
        default:
            t *= 1.09361, n = t > 1760 ? (t / 1760).toFixed(2) + " miles" : Math.ceil(t) + " yd"
    }
    return n
}
```

**My own Map.js (this is how I currently initialise the map):**

```
// Map.js
function initMap() {
    const drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        draw: {
            marker  : false,
            polygon : true,
            polyline: {
                metric: true
            },
            rectangle: true,
            circle   : {
                metric: true
            }
        },
        edit: false
    });

    const map = L.map('map').setView([CONFIG.MAP.LATITUDE, CONFIG.MAP.LONGITUDE], CONFIG.MAP.ZOOMLEVEL)
        .on('popupopen', e => {
            $(e.popup._source._icon).attr('src', CONFIG.IMG.ELEC_ACTIVE);
        })
        .on('popupclose', e => {
            $(e.popup._source._icon).attr('src', CONFIG.IMG.ELEC_INACTIVE);
        });

    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
        accessToken: CONFIG.MAP.ACCESSTOKEN
    }).addTo(map);

    map.addControl(drawControl);

    const icon = L.icon({
        iconUrl    : CONFIG.IMG.ELEC_INACTIVE,
        popupAnchor: [125, 25],
        iconSize   : [14, 18]
    });

    const markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
        maxClusterRadius(zoom) {
            return (zoom <= 14) ? 80 : 1; // radius in pixels
        }
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < 150; i++) {
        // Remove everything except the CONFIG variables, Math.random() serves as testing display.
        const marker = L.marker([(Math.random() * 0.05) - 0.03 + CONFIG.MAP.LATITUDE, (Math.random() * 0.05) - 0.03 + CONFIG.MAP.LONGITUDE], {
            icon,
            closeButton: false
        }).addTo(map).bindPopup('<p class="c-popup__content"><a class="c-popup__link" href="#">Add pole to selection</a><span class="c-popup__address">Marnixstraat 246, 1016 TL, Amsterdam<span></p>', {
            'className': 'c-popup'
        })
            .on('click', () => {
                $('.c-popup').css('width', 'auto');
            });
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    }

    map.addLayer(markers);
}
```

Side note: I'm aware of this question:
[Leaflet Draw Plugin: How to hide/show drawing tools by Layer Type dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676090/leaflet-draw-plugin-how-to-hide-show-drawing-tools-by-layer-type-dynamically)

But this top answer doesn't quite answer the problem I'm encountering, in addition, I would prefer to avoid writing a new function to re-initialise my controls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the [API documentation](https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-0.4.9.html#drawoptions) is not exactly in par with the [source code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/v0.4.9/src/ext/GeometryUtil.js#L54-L108) indeed (version `v0.4.9`).

1) The docs are not explicit, but the `circle` options are of the same form as the `polyline` options, but they do not directly extend them. I.e. specifying `metric` on `polyline` does not enforce it for `circle` as well. => You also need to specify the `metric` option on `circle`. (same for `polygon` and `rectangle` I guess)

2) Even though the `metric` option accepts a boolean, it must be either the `"metric"` string or used in conjunction with `feet: false` option for it to take effect.

```js
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        circle   : {
            metric: 'metric'
        }
    }
});
```

Or:

```js
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    draw: {
        circle   : {
            metric: true,
            feet: false
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/qur/1/edit?html,output

Note: known issue, see [Leaflet.draw issue #690](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/690). The proposed workaround is exactly what is described above.